# asp.net calendar is too slow on OnDayRender

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I have a calendar in my asp.net application.  OnDayRender I need to bind a value for each specific day from the database.  So, I establish a connection to the db for each day. And, this slows down the system a lot.  What would be a better way of doing this?  How can I get these data for all month at once and display it appropriately?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing the database query in `OnDayRender`, do it when your form initially loads, and fetch the data for the whole month (or whatever the range of the calendar is) into a `List` or something similar. Then your `OnDayRender` code can just fetch the data from the list.

It's hard to say more than that without a better idea of what you're doing, but that's the gist of it: fetch all the relevant data from the database into memory at the start, and then grab individual days from memory when you need them.

Comment: I just need to retrieve a number for each day.  My problem is, each month has different number of days.  How can I write a query for this?

Comment: @erkaner: Well if you know which month you're fetching, you'd just do a query with a range. It's hard to say how to write a query without having any information at all about your database schema or what you're fetching beyond "a number".